# creating variable name by concatenating strings in php

Tags: php, string

I have a file named questions.php with an array as follows :

```
$question12 = array("Which is the tallest mountain","Mt Everest");
```

I am including this file in another file as follows :

```
require_once('questions.php');
$var = 12;
$question = '$question'.$var.'[0]';
echo $question;
```

The above code just outputs the following **string** (not the contents of the variable):

```
$question12[0]
```

But I want the variable **$question** to contain the string present in **$question12[0]**.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Just use $question12[0]

Comment: why not just use  $question12[0]

Comment: of course ...directly using $question12[0] works..but that's not that point..
i want to generate a php variable .. and i am stuck..

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Variable variable is not recommended, but the answer is below:

```
$question = ${'question'.$var}[0];
```

Comment: Why is variable variable not reccommended?

Comment: @Piersv maybe because dereferencing a variable property that is an array has different semantics between PHP 5 and PHP 7, and the fact that this can always be circumvented by using an array. I do not see other downsides.

Comment: Variable Variables work fine in PHP 5.6 and @jordan-doyle gave the best answer below.

Comment: @Chiwda Is this equally good for PHP 8?

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for variable variables.

```
$id = 12;
$q = "question{$id}";
$q = $$q[0];
```

You should seriously consider looking into multidimensional arrays to stop having multiple arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Just use $question12[0]. It will give you the desired output.

Using the $var you can do it like this:-

`$question = ${'question'. $var}[index]`;

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, im going to get some hate for mentioning something `evil` but still it is one of the options

```
<?php
$question12 = array("Which is the tallest mountain","Mt Everest");
$var = 12;
$question = '$question'.$var.'[0]';
eval("echo $question;");
?>
```

P.S: [eval()](http://php.net/eval) is that `evil`

Comment: `rename_function('eval', 'evil');` now ypu can use the function `evil`