# create single variables from two arrays

Tags: php

I have two php arrays

```
$arra = array('one', 'two', 'five', 'seven');

$arrb = array('black', 'white', 'gold', 'silver');
```

I need to create variables, like this way:

```
foreach ($arra as $el) {
    $el = $arrb[index of $el];
}
```

So echoing resulting variables:

`echo $one` should be `black`
`echo $two` should be `white`  and so on.

How to do that?

Comment: extract(array_combine($arra, $arrb)); http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: @splash58, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually set a variable's name using a variables value, You need something like this:

```
for($x=0; $x < count($arra); $x++){
    $$arra[$x] = $arrb[$x];
}
```

Notice the double `$$`. This is not a mistake.

Comment: Glad I could help, what changed?

Comment: some typo in my code. it's ok now. where is a reference for double `$`, pls?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and then use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to make dynamic variables. `array_combine()`- **Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values**

```
<?php
 $arra = array('one', 'two', 'five', 'seven');
 $arrb = array('black', 'white', 'gold', 'silver');
 $result = array_combine($arra, $arrb);
 foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    ${$key} = $value;
 }
 echo $two;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/VPNQh

**OR** use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) after combining `$arra` and `$arrb`. `extracts()`-
 **Imports variables into the current symbol table from an array.**

```
<?php
$arra = array('one', 'two', 'five', 'seven');
$arrb = array('black', 'white', 'gold', 'silver');
$result = array_combine($arra, $arrb);
extract($result, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME,'');
echo "$one, $two, $five, $seven";
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/VW55k

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$arra = array('one', 'two', 'five', 'seven');

$arrb = array('black', 'white', 'gold', 'silver');

foreach($arra as $key=>$ela) {
  $elb = $arrb[$key];
  ${$ela} = $elb;
}

echo $one;
echo $two;
echo $five;
echo $seven;
```

For using strings as variables I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955258/creating-variable-name-by-concatenating-strings-in-php) helpful.